# AWC CLI S3 Multipart Upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

According to documentation below AWS CLI uses multipart upload if file is bigger than `64MB`. 
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/topic/s3-config.html

Also by default each part has `8MB`, as S3 multipart supports up-to `10000` parts, it means AWS CLI can only send a file as multipart if the file do not exceed `8MB * 10000 = ~78GB`. Am I correct in this assumption?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/qfacts.html

We can change this behavior if we configure `multipart_chunksize` on AWS CLI.
I understand we should keep each part as small as possible to take full advantage of multipart upload.

My question is, how can we handle this configuration in order to take full advantage of multipart upload and be able to upload file of difference sizes higher than `78GB`?

To avoid confusion, the question is about usage of `multipart`. AWS CLI is working fine, I am not facing issues, I just want to make sure it will use `multipart` upload when we need to send file of different sizes.

Comment: Your assumption is correct except a minor error which is `8MB * 10000` should be `80GB`. Back to your question, since S3 has a hard limit on the maximum number of parts allowed in one multipart upload, so it's not possible to do it in one multipart upload if you want to take advantages from both of them. An alternative could be initiating several multipart uploads, complete each one separately, and finally initiate another multipart upload to assemble them in S3.

Comment: If I use two multiparts uploads, will I end-up with two files or one? My point is, I want to upload a file that is 150GB bigger, if I change `multipart_chunksize` to `16MB` I can do it. But if I need to send another file that is 200GB bigger, I can't, I need to change `multipart_chunksize` again.

Comment: You seem to know that the solution is to increase `multipart_chunksize`. What's stopping you doing this?

Comment: @jarmod Yes if I change this parameter it works fine, I am not facing issues. My question about how to handle this change. As I know we can do it only per profile (default or not), nor per execution. If I change this on default profile and we have two different process sending files, one of them will overwrite the change from the other.

Comment: Now I understand your questions: aws cli will use multi part upload on its own.

Comment: OK, that explains things. Does upload of a very large file actually fail because of these chunking defaults? I'm assuming you don't have many profile that you'd need to do this to so maybe you could just set up multiple variants of the same profile: myapp, myapp-m, myapp-xl. Each one has the same credentials but different S3 chunking configuration (M being a medium value, XL being the max you need). Or you could just script the upload using python/boto3 and have complete control.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is not correct. You can upload files up to 5TB using multipart upload to S3.

You are right that you can upload a maximum of 10.000 chunks for one multipart upload.

The maximum size for any chunk is 5GB and for anything bigger than that you must upload using multipart upload. So you can use any size up to 5GB for your multipart upload.

Keeping your chunks as small as possible may actually hurt your upload time, as setting up a connection is time consuming. Having small chunks may hurt from connection setup time, having larger chunks may hurt you because some uploads may fail and you need to redo it. This is where getting the right chunk size is important.

We're using chunks of 100MB in a project where we're uploading files over 100 GB and it works. Using this limit we are limiting the maximum file size to 1TB, but that's ok for our needs.

Comment: 5 TB is a maximum object size, but not necessarily AWS CLI will send it using multipart. Yes, it always work to send file bigger than 100 GB using AWS CLI. But the question is, how it send the file, as multipart or not?

Comment: Anything bigger than 5GB is sent using multipart.

Comment: So AWS CLI only send file using multipart if the file is bigger than 5GB, is it what you are saying?

Comment: No, I'm saying that for anything bigger than 5GB will surely use multipart upload, but will use it even for lower file sizes. You shouldn't worry about this, at will handle any file size.

Comment: If you're using a multipart_chunk of 100mb, what is the connection timeout set at?  is that not a huge chunk for laggy 4g mobile connections?   And if it fails the entire 100mb chunk will need to be retried.

Comment: I don't know the timeout and I don't think you can change that. The timeout would be on the S3 side and as such you don't have a saying in that. You may end up with chunks that need to be retried, that's true. The talk wasn't about mobile connections, but uploading large files in general. When uploading very large files you need a reliable connection and that means that you don't use mobile data (usually). You can use smaller chunks, of course, but then you lose time setting up the connections.